# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: request

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, httprequest, httpresponsemessage

I'm creating a unit test using nunit and all of this code works fine in runtime.

I have this protected `HttpResponseMessage` code below that is being called by my controller when it returns.

However, an error:

> "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: request" is displaying.

And when I check the request, it is actually `null`.

Question:
How will I code my unit test to return the `HttpResponseMessage`?

Error is shown in this line:

```
  protected HttpResponseMessage Created<T>(T result) => Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, Envelope.Ok(result));
```

Here is my Controller:

```
    [Route("employees")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateEmployee([FromBody] CreateEmployeeModel model)
    {
        //**Some code here**//

        return Created(new EmployeeModel
        {
            EmployeeId = employee.Id,
            CustomerId = employee.CustomerId,
            UserId = employee.UserId,
            FirstName = employee.User.FirstName,
            LastName = employee.User.LastName,
            Email = employee.User.Email,

            MobileNumber = employee.MobileNumber,
            IsPrimaryContact = employee.IsPrimaryContact,
            OnlineRoleId = RoleManager.GetOnlineRole(employee.CustomerId, employee.UserId).Id,
            HasMultipleCompanies = EmployeeManager.HasMultipleCompanies(employee.UserId)
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 25):

The reason why you are getting:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Web.Http.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Value cannot be null.

is because the `Request` object is `null`.

[image]

The solution for that is to create an instance of your controller in your tests such as:

```
    var myApiController = new MyApiController
    {
        Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(),
        Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
    };
```

In this way, when creating a new instance of the `MyApiController` class we are initializing the `Request` object. Moreover, it is also necessary to provide the associated configuration object.

Finally, an example of Unit Test for your Api Controller could be:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyApiControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateEmployee_Returns_HttpStatusCode_Created()
    {
        // Arrange
        var controller = new MyApiController
        {
            Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(),
            Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
        };

        var employee = new CreateEmployeeModel
        {
            Id = 1
        };

        // Act
        var response = controller.CreateEmployee(employee);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Created);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think what happens is that you are not instantiating or assigning your Request property (`HttpRequestMessage`) when you new up your Controller. I believe it's mandatory to specify the request prior calling into the Api method via your unit test.

You may also require a Configuration (`HttpConfiguration`):

```
sut = new YourController()
    {
        Request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://www.unittests.com") },

        Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
    };
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: This worked for me:
MyController controller = new MyController() { Request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage() };

Answer (score 3):

Also, if your controller has injections, you can do:

```
var controller= new MyController(injectionA, injectionB, injectionC)
{
    Request = new HttpRequestMessage(),
    Configuration = new HttpConfiguration()
};
```

I find them all on the easy to understand [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api) now.